# this.get('x') returns ' undefined' instead of 'undefined'

Tags: ember.js

In a form-component I have an observer that tests if a property is valid before to start further validations.
So I checked if the property has not yet been defined (happens at initialization f.e.)

```
if(typeof this.get('myProperty') !== 'undefined') { 
    //do smth 
}
```

Then I realized that `this.get` would not return a type of 'undefined' but a string with the value undefined.
Fair enough.

**BUT**

```
console.log(this.get('myProperty'));
```

gives me ' undefined' instead of 'undefined' - notice the space before 'undefined'!

Is this a bug?
Or do I really have to check for ' undefined' with a space and is there a reason for that?

*Ember-cli: 1.13.7

Ember: 2.0.1*

Comment: `this.get` should return `undefined` not `'undefined'`. Are sure you aren't setting it to `' undefined'` at some other place? Try testing `undefined === this.get('missingProperty');`, it should return `true` if the property was never defined.

Comment: I'm even setting it to `''` in the component. This is in an observer, during initialization of the component it first returns `' undefined'`, then `' '`, then `''`.

Comment: An observer isn't supposed to return anything, are you thinking of a computed property?

Comment: I think I found the (my) error. `myProperty` is indeed set via another computed Property. Thanks for your hint. Not yet solved, but I think you're right!

Answer (score 0):

How about you use Ember.isNone or Ember.isEmpty. For the opposite Ember.isPresent

Returns true if argument is null or undefined.

```
Ember.isNone(); // true
Ember.isNone(null); // true
Ember.isNone(undefined); // true
Ember.isNone(''); // false
Ember.isNone([]); // false
Ember.isNone(function(){}); // false
```

This utility function constrains the rules on Ember.none by returning false for empty string and empty arrays.

```
Ember.isEmpty(); // true
Ember.isEmpty(null); // true
Ember.isEmpty(undefined); // true
Ember.isEmpty(''); // true
Ember.isEmpty([]); // true
Ember.isEmpty('tobias fünke'); // false
Ember.isEmpty([0,1,2]); // false
```